# HTTP POST request on Android

Tags: java, android, http, http-post

For the last two hours i've been trying to make a POST request to this page http://www.halebop.se/butik/byt_behall_nummer/ and tried to send **numberToPort**. However i get a bunch of cookies and a 302 moved temporarily back.

All i want to do is send the POST request with the number and get the final page back. On iOS, i do this using ASIHTTPRequest which handles the redirect and cookies.

iOS code:

```
NSString *halebopURLString = @"http://www.halebop.se/kontantkort/byt_behall_nummer/#";
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:halebopURLString]];
[request setPostValue:halebopNumber forKey:@"numberToPort"];
[request setPostValue:@"continue" forKey:@"action"];
[request setPostValue:@"submit" forKey:@"submit"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

How do i do this on Android?

As an alternative, a PHP solution is acceptable.

Edit: Tried this, it gives no output and no exceptions. I have the internet permission. Expected result: Send POST, get 302 and cookies back, send cookies to URL from 302 and get HTML back (Checked with FireBug) however i get nothing.

```
try {
        InputStream myInputStream =null;
        URL url;
        url = new URL("http://www.halebop.se/kontantkort/byt_behall_nummer/#");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write("numberToPort="+n+"&action=continue&submit=submit");
        wr.flush();
        myInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        wr.close();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myInputStream), 4096);
        String line;
        StringBuilder sbResult =  new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sbResult.append(line);
            Log.d(TAG, "Line "+line);
        }
        rd.close();
        String contentOfMyInputStream = sbResult.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Output "+contentOfMyInputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: What about the Android code you are currently attempting to do this with?

Comment: Was too messy, Its my first Android app. Will post if i cant get emboss's suggestion to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can set the post parameters:

```
            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);
    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test1","test1" ));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test2", "test2" ));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

    response = getResponse(httpost);
```

[Here](http://krishrud.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-set-httppost-parameters-on.html) is the detailed explanation about the code.

I also explained How to retrieve HTTP cookies from your response and set them into request [here](http://krishrud.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-http-cookies-jsessionid.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HttpUrlConnection, then [HttpUrlConnection#setFollowRedirects](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29) might be what you are after. Set it to `true` to make it automatically resolve the redirect. Even better to use `setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` since blindly following redirects (what the static `setFollowRedirects` would cause) is frowned upon from a security perspective.

Comment: Sounds good, will try as soon as i get back to my box. Will it hold on to, and send back all the cookies just like ASIHTTPRequest as well?

Comment: Not back at my box yet but i checked the docs about cookies. Is it correct that all i need are these two lines to make it handle cookies for me automatically?  **CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
   CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);**

Comment: Tried it without luck. No output and no exceptions. Please see edited post on top for code.